# Selecting a Named Range Only to Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pulling raw data into a template, but I have no guarantee that between teams they'll be using the same UI template to pull the data. I can check to make sure the data I want is there, but they might be in different columns between teams.

So, my macro names the ranges (each is a full column based on the header name) and then will, hopefully, go to select desired named ranges to copy and paste.

Of course, these data sets are various sizes and I feel like I'm tripping over a super simple thing.

What I want to do is select my named range, but only to the last row, and then paste the values into my template. Except, I can't figure out how to only select to the last row.

Here's my current bit of troublesome code:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
Range("PullPlacementname" & LastRow).Copy
```

Running this gives me a run-time error '1004', method 'range' of object failed. This confuses me, cuz I've used this method before successfully.

A slight tinker, below, gave me the same issue

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

I've tried adding an additional Dim

```
Dim PullPlacementname As Range
Set PullPlacementname = ActiveWorkbook.SheetName("Pull").Range("PullPlacementname")
```

But the second line gives me a run-time error of '438', object doesn't support this property or method.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: You probably meant to use `Worksheets("Pull")` instead of `SheetName("Pull")` in the last statement.

Comment: @YowE3K, potentially. But even that fix gave me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
Dim c As Long
With Worksheets("Pull")
    c = .Range("PullPlacementname").Column ' assuming the range name only contains one column
    .Range(.Cells(1, c), .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).Copy
End With
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!  I love how this will work with all of my ranges.